# npm install permission denied Mac M1

Tags: node.js, macos, vue.js, npm-install, permission-denied

I've tried everything, this only shows an inch of what I've tried, can anyone help? I replaced my name with an a, that's the only thing I changed in the error code

````
a@Air-von-A kanban % npm install
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/a/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/0f/7d
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/a/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/0f/7d'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/a/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/0f/7d
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/a/.npm/_logs/2024-01-06T17_01_26_417Z-debug-0.log
a@Air-von-A kanban % sudo npm install -g yarn

added 1 package in 650ms
a@Air-von-A kanban % npm install
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/a/Downloads/kanban/node_modules/@vue/compiler-core
npm ERR! dest /Users/a/Downloads/kanban/node_modules/@vue/.compiler-core-ZXEc73Pt
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/a/Downloads/kanban/node_modules/@vue/compiler-core' -> '/Users/a/Downloads/kanban/node_modules/@vue/.compiler-core-ZXEc73Pt'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/avissataghizadeh/.npm/_logs/2024-01-06T17_02_33_402Z-debug-0.log
a@Air-von-A kanban % ```
````

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with permissions in the home directory of your machine. You can use `sudo` before each npm command to fix this, but to permanently fix this without having to do `sudo` everytime, run the following:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

Comment: still got the same error code :(